# Pass image view from collection view to a new view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

How can I pass data a view controller that has images inside collection view to another view controller, when clicking a image? So when I click the image, it opens in another view controller.

cellForItemAtIndexPath code:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

        cell.imageText.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 3
        let myColor : UIColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue:0.0, alpha: 0.15)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.025)
        cell.layer.borderColor = myColor.CGColor

        let post = self.arrayOfDetails[indexPath.row]
        cell.currentUserLabel.text = post.username
        cell.imageText.text = post.text

        cell.uploadedTimeLabel.text = post.CreatedAt.timeAgo

        cell.imageView.setImageWithUrl(NSURL(string: post.image)!, placeHolderImage: UIImage(named: "Placeholder"))

        return cell
    }
```

Details:

```
struct Details {
    var username:String!
    var text:String!
    var CreatedAt:NSDate!
    var image:String!
    init(username:String,text:String,CreatedAt:NSDate,image:String){

        self.username = username
        self.text = text
        self.CreatedAt = CreatedAt
        self.image = image
    }
}
```

didSelectItemAtIndexPath method:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    {
         self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showImage", sender: self)
    }
```

Any suggestions please?

Comment: where is your didSelectItem method?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on if your using Storyboards or doing it programmatically, I would go about it in the same way:

Set up the properties you need in your new VC to be publicly accessible, and then either in prepareForSegue or in your delegate method for when they click on a cell, pass the info you want into the properties of your new VC, then in `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear`, etc. setup everything you need with that data.

Easiest solution of course is to just pass in the imageView, but it may not be the right resolution, etc. So pass in any data needed to recreate it in either you `prepareForSegue` or in your `didSelectItem` method, and use it in your new VC